# Return all rows from a table for which the cat_id cannot be found in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database where `article.cat_id` is linked to `category.id`.

I removed a few rows from `category` and now I want to select or remove all rows from `article` that link to an `id` in `category` that doesn't exist. Unfortunately, I don't exactly know which `id`s have been removed.

Is there an SQL way to check to return all rows from `article` for which there is no `category.id` equal to `article.cat_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 where Table_1.ID not in (SELECT Table_2.ID FROM Table_2)
```

the inner select it will select all the IDs from Table 2 while the outer select it will base the returned rows where the ID doesn't exist in TABLE 2

Comment: If you add some explanation to this answer I'm willing to accept it ;)

Comment: @CamilStaps: to complete the picture: this will only work correctly if there are no `NULL` values in the the ID column of table_2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, that's a good note, thanks. In this case it's an int with primary key & auto increment, so there won't be NULL values, but it's a good note for future users!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE a.*
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN category c
ON a.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

Change `DELETE` to `SELECT` first to make sure it's what you want.

Comment: this should be `DELETE a` instead of `DELETE a.*` -- `:)`

Comment: Actually, `a.*` is also allowed. The documentation says `tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
delete a
from article a
left outer join category c on c.id = a.cat_id
where c.id is null
```